# Jquery dynamically initialize

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Partial View

```
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="InspectionQuestionAnswers.Index" value="@Model.GenID">
    @Html.Hidden("InspectionQuestionAnswers[" + Model.GenID + "].GenID", Model.GenID, new { id = "InspectionQuestionAnswers_" + Model.GenID + "__InspectionQuestionID" })
    @Html.Hidden("InspectionQuestionAnswers[" + Model.GenID + "].ID", Model.ID, new { id = "InspectionQuestionAnswers_" + Model.GenID + "__InspectionQuestionID", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.Hidden("InspectionQuestionAnswers[" + Model.GenID + "].InspectionTemplateQuestionID", Model.InspectionTemplateQuestionID, new { id = "InspectionQuestionAnswers_" + Model.GenID + "__InspectionQuestionID", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.TextBox("InspectionQuestionAnswers[" + Model.GenID + "].Answer", Model.Answer, new { id = "InspectionQuestionAnswers_" + Model.GenID + "__InspectionQuestionID", @class = "form-control" })
</td>
<td question_type="row_default">
    @Html.TextBox("InspectionQuestionAnswers[" + Model.GenID + "].Identifier", Model.Identifier, new { id = "InspectionQuestionAnswers_" + Model.GenID + "__InspectionQuestionID", @class = "form-control" })
</td>
<td question_type="row_default">
    @Html.CheckBox("InspectionQuestionAnswers[" + Model.GenID + "].ForcePhoto", Model.ForcePhoto, new {id = "InspectionQuestionAnswers_" + Model.GenID + "__InspectionQuestionID", @class = "checkbox checkbox-inline"}) Require Proof
</td>
<td question_type="row_stock">
    @Html.TextBox("InspectionQuestionAnswers[" + Model.GenID + "].MinStock", Model.MinStock, new { id = "InspectionQuestionAnswers_" + Model.GenID + "__InspectionQuestionID", @class = "form-control" })
</td>
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right ajax-remove" href="@Url.Action("DeleteAnswer")/@Model.ID">Delete</a>
</td>
```

This Partial view is added using Ajax to a table. but then the class `ajax-remove` is not initialized even though I have put it in the following function `$(document).ready(function ()`

Here is the Ajax method

```
        $(".ajax-remove").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var sender = $(this).closest('tr');
            var elementUrl = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: elementUrl,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    sender.remove();
                }
            });
        });
```

The above Ajax never happens, it just simply redirects to the url as a white page.

How can I ensure that if I dynamically add html to the page that the jquery methods/listners are initialized

Comment: is this script in partial view?

Comment: The Ajax script is in my Layout page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your html is being generated on fly dynamically via ajax call, you will need [delegated event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
 $(document).on("click",".ajax-remove", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ............
            ............
        });
```

you can use the closest parent which is available on the DOM load for better performance instead of `document`.

Comment: Perfect thank you. can you show example on `closest parent`

Comment: Instead of document you would apply parent container div Id like $("#container")